# CPU Limit for Fluentd agent

Tags: resources, cpu, fluentd

I am using Fluentd to tail data from multiple files (one worker for one file). Recently  the number of tailed files increased, and so did that of workers. That all resulted in Fluentd's overusing CPU resources. So it needs to be limited on resources usage.

But I'm quite confused on how much resources should I allocate for a Fluentd container (with N workers for example). Are there any tips or formulas to decide CPU resources allocated for a Fluentd container?

Thanks a lot.